When solving for phase, why doesnt the author consider location of the complex numbers?
The following shows up in a textbook (Control Systems: Principles & Design, M Gopal, 3rd edition, example 7.1)
F(s) is just a function in a complex number, mapping to another complex number (for those familiar with control theory, it's an open-loop transfer function). $\sigma$ and $\omega$ are just the real & imaginary parts of the input to the function. Its defined as follows, taken from that example,
$$F(s = \sigma + j\omega) = \frac{K \left( \sigma + b + j\omega \right)}{\left( \sigma + a_1 \right)\left( \sigma + a_2 \right) - \omega^2 + j\omega \left( 2\sigma + a_1 + a_2 \right)}\\\\
$$
The author claims that the following is the angle of F(s) taken as a phasor,
$$\angle F(s = \sigma + j\omega) = \tan^{-1} \frac{\omega}{\sigma + b} - \tan^{-1} \frac{\omega \left( 2\sigma + a_1 + a_2 \right)}{\left( \sigma + a_1 \right) \left( \sigma + a_2 \right) - \omega^2}$$
I dont think this is correct unless both complex numbers (the numerator & denominator) are on the right side of the complex plane, because of how arctan works. Is that right? We would need a $\pi$ offset, per term, if not.
Is it normal that I spent about an hour trying to make sense of whats going on here? Is it handwaving? Its difficult for me to ignore handwaving sometimes & I end up wasting a lot of time not knowing what to do.

I agree that the arctangent function is sometimes used carelessly, either in writing formulas or even in practical computations. The latter will result in real problems.
In your cases, I can't be sure what's going because I don't know the meaning of the constants. It could be that the corresponding complex numbers all have a positive real part and everything is correct. If that's not the case, then the author was a bit careless, and he actually meant the atan2 function.
In such cases I prefer to write
$$\tan\phi=\frac{y}{x}$$
which is true,
instead of
$$\phi\stackrel{?}{=}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
which might not be true.
This gets rid of all problems (in writing) related to the arctangent function, and I hope that people who are interested in computing $\phi$ know how to properly invert the tangent function. Luckily, virtually all scientific programs have an implementation of the atan2 function, and we just need to remind ourselves to use it.

The author assumes s to be any complex number. The numerator at least could be anything right? (not sure about denominator, it looks messy) You shouldn't be able to directly use arctan directly I think (at least to get numerator phase). I think the author was being sloppy.

@YeslinSequeira: It's only about the second expression in your question. And there, only the denominators are important. If for some reason they are positive, the arctangent is correct. But anyway, what is usually meant by $\tan^{-1}$ is the correct (!) inversion of the tangent function.

I'm confused about what you mean tbh. All constants are positive and real. You need phase of the numerator term & the denominator term to find phase of the overall function right? First find numerator & denominator phase, both expressed as complex numbers in rect. form there, then maybe use Euler's form to see that the overall phase results in a difference.

@YeslinSequeira: Right, phase(z1/z2)=phase(z1)-phase(z2). That's what I meant when I said you only need to look at the second formula, which is the difference of the phases. If both denominators of that expression are positive, the arctan will give the correct result. But again, just use atan2 and forget the rest.

Ah, I see what you meant

The author went on to use the difference of arctans identity on the second expression (which I looked up, you can only use it if the difference is within arctans range, the author doesn't mention this). I can't exactly treat it like atan2... Is mathematical sloppiness normal in engineering textbooks?

@YeslinSequeira: Well, you shouldn't expect the same degree of rigour as in mathematical literature, but formulas and results should be correct, and limits of their applicability should be discussed. So, have you found an error or is the final result correct after all?

I'm not sure... It might be correct, I don't have any way to verify by hand, neither do I have any ideas for alternate solutions. The aim of the example is to get a root locus.

Im giving up...

@YeslinSequeira: You could formulate a new question with the aim of checking the final result.

I ended up adding a $(+\pi)$ to the equations, to indicate a possible offset. I did some math and concluded that the arctan difference identity can be applied, with some ambiguity about a possible $\pi$ offset, and also the inital formulation called for a possible offset too. So what I ended up getting out of the equations is a narrowing-down of my search for "angle condition" regions (regions where F(s) has a 180 degree phase, as desired by the C.E. F(s)+1=0 ), which is identical to what the textbook has.

Apparently, that (very messy) expression ends up giving us the equation of a circle (really dont feel like doing the algebra, so Ill just accept that). The way we got here wasnt foolproof, we dont know for sure F(s) has a 180 phase, so I think you'd have some doubt if every point on the circle works. The textbook says its "easy" to verify that the circle satisfies the angle condition, hence proved intimidation ig.
